# Typescript: incompatible types with React spread props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm running into a typing error, specifically when I spread over props as I pass it into a React Component.

```
type FooLevel = 1 | 2 | 3

interface FooProps {
  fooLevel: FooLevel;
}

// Typing for a SFC
const Foo = ({
  fooLevel
}: FooProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Your foo level {fooLevel}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

// Foo invocation: 
const props = { fooLevel: 1 }
<Foo fooLevel={1} />   // this works
<Foo {...props} />     // error - Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FooLevel'
```

It looks like it's having trouble connecting a `number` to a `FooLevel`. Is this by design? Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by casting `1` to `FooLevel`. Though I feel like this shouldn't be an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `props` to `FooProps` and `1 as FooLevel` manually:

```
type FooLevel = 1 | 2 | 3;

interface FooProps {
    fooLevel: FooLevel;
}

const Foo = (props: FooProps) => (
    <div>
        <span>Your foo level {props.fooLevel}</span>
    </div>
);

const myProps: FooProps = { fooLevel: 1 };

const app = props => (
    <div>
        <Foo fooLevel={1 as FooLevel} />
        <Foo {...myProps} /> 
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by setting the type for `props` manually, since it is inferred as a number type instead of a `FooLevel`

```
const props: FooProps = { fooLevel: 1 };
```